# Can Google Apps Script call a python script?

Tags: python, google-apps-script

I have a python script that uses a python api to fetch data from a data provider, then after manipulating the data, writes some of that data to Google Sheets (via the Google Sheets python api). So my workflow to update the data is to open the python file in VS Code, and run it from there, then switch to the spreadsheet to see the updated data.

Is there a way to call this python script from Google Sheets using Google Apps Script? If so, that would be more efficient; I could link the GAS script to a macro button on the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps Script runs in the *cloud* at Google's servers rather than in your computer, and has no access to *local* resources such as Python scripts in your system.

To call a resource in the *cloud*, use the [URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch).

Answer (score 2):

Currently, I am using following hack.

The appsscript behind gsheet command button writes parameters in a sheet called Parameters. And the python function on my local machine checks that Parameters sheet in that google workbook every 5 seconds. If there are no parameters, then it exists. And if there are parameters, then it executes the main code

When the code is deployed on service account, the portion which is polling remains inactive. And the appsscript directly makes a call directly to python code in service account.

There are many reasons why I need to call python function on LOCAL machine from gsheet. One reason is --- debugging is better in local machine and cumbersome on service account. Another reason is --- certain files can be put on local machines and we do not want to move these files to workspace. And gsheet needs data from these files.

This is a HACK I am using
.
I am looking for a better way that this "python code keeps polling" method.